# I launched RDS SQL Server (SQL Server Web Edition) when I ran the query and It is throwing permission denied error

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, sql-server-ce

I ran below query and error is

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysschedules', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

SQL Server Web Edition
Engine version
15.00.4073.23.v1

How to resolve this?

```
SELECT [sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID],
       [sJOB].[name] AS [JobName],
       [sDBP].[name] AS [JobOwner],
       [sCAT].[name] AS [JobCategory],
       [sJOB].[description] AS [JobDescription],
       CASE [sJOB].[enabled] WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' END AS [IsEnabled],
       [sJOB].[date_created] AS [JobCreatedOn],
       [sJOB].[date_modified] AS [JobLastModifiedOn],
       [sSVR].[name] AS [OriginatingServerName],
       [sJSTP].[step_id] AS [JobStartStepNo],
       [sJSTP].[step_name] AS [JobStartStepName],
       CASE WHEN [sSCH].[schedule_uid] IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS [IsScheduled],
       [sSCH].[schedule_uid] AS [JobScheduleID],
       [sSCH].[name] AS [JobScheduleName],
       CASE [sJOB].[delete_level]
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Never'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'On Success'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'On Failure'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'On Completion'
       END AS [JobDeletionCriterion]
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] [sJOB]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[sys].[servers] [sSVR] ON [sJOB].[originating_server_id] = [sSVR].[server_id]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[syscategories] [sCAT] ON [sJOB].[category_id] = [sCAT].[category_id]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] [sJSTP] ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJSTP].[job_id]
                                                 AND [sJOB].[start_step_id] = [sJSTP].[step_id]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[sys].[syslogins] [sDBP] ON [sJOB].[owner_sid] = [sDBP].[sid]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules] [sJOBSCH] ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBSCH].[job_id]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules] [sSCH] ON [sJOBSCH].[schedule_id] = [sSCH].[schedule_id]
ORDER BY [JobName];
```

Comment: I highly recommend formatting your query

Comment: You *need* to get into the habit of making ***good*** use of whitespace and linebreaks in your writing, including code. It makes very difficult to unreadable text *Far* more readable. As for the error, it's literally telling you the problem here. What about said error don't you understand?

Comment: Even though I have admin privilege, I am not able to grant the permission

Comment: How are you determining that you have "admin privileges"? Do you mean you are a member of the sysadmin role? Does this query return any rows? `use msdb;
select * from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'database') where permission_name = 'take ownership'`

Comment: It is not giving any result, Only 0 rows are affected

Comment: @allmhuran Could you please give me some work around. I am new to DB.

Comment: You need to ask your DBA for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as of now, this is not supported in RDS. It looks like RDS doesn't give you access to query these system tables:

- `[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps]`
- `[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules]`
- `[msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules]`

Corresponding AWS forum thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220807

You need to remove joins to these tables from your query, which gives you following - which is possible to execute against RDS for SQL Server instance:

```
SELECT [sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID],
       [sJOB].[name] AS [JobName],
       [sDBP].[name] AS [JobOwner],
       [sCAT].[name] AS [JobCategory],
       [sJOB].[description] AS [JobDescription],
       CASE [sJOB].[enabled] WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' WHEN 0 THEN 'FALSE' END AS [IsEnabled],
       [sJOB].[date_created] AS [JobCreatedOn],
       [sJOB].[date_modified] AS [JobLastModifiedOn],
       [sSVR].[name] AS [OriginatingServerName],
       CASE [sJOB].[delete_level]
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Never'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'On Success'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'On Failure'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'On Completion'
       END AS [JobDeletionCriterion]
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] [sJOB]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[sys].[servers] [sSVR] ON [sJOB].[originating_server_id] = [sSVR].[server_id]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[syscategories] [sCAT] ON [sJOB].[category_id] = [sCAT].[category_id]
     LEFT JOIN [msdb].[sys].[syslogins] [sDBP] ON [sJOB].[owner_sid] = [sDBP].[sid]
ORDER BY [JobName];
```